# Using Hilt, how to inject into a class that does not have a context?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a class named `NetworkManager`. Since it is not one of the Android Components, I am using custom entry point, `NetworkManagerEntryPoint` with one `fun` that returns `NetworkClient` object which is what I want to inject.

Now, to inject an instance of this class using Hilt, I believe I need to use one of the Helper methods in `EntryPointAccessors`. But all of them requires a reference to android components. So, do I really have to pass an android component like Context to my class to inject an object using Hilt?

```
class NetworkManager() {

    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    @EntryPoint
    interface NetworkManagerEntryPoint {
        fun getNetworkClient(): NetworkClient
    }

    var defaultNetworkClient: NetworkClient = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
        context, // Do I have to pass a context to this class to use Hilt?
        NetworkManagerEntryPoint::class.java
    ).getNetworkClient()

    fun <R : Any> executeRequest(
            request:Request<R>,
            networkClient: NetworkClient = defaultNetworkClient
    ): Response<R> {
        // Do some operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there maybe you can try this way i have done , i follow the mvvm pattern

My RetrofitApi

```
interface RetrofitApi {
@GET("endpoint")
suspend fun getApi():Response<RetrofitApiResponse>
}
```

My NetworkModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule{

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideApi(): RetrofitApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RetrofitApi::class.java)

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRepository(retrofitApi:RetrofitApi) : MainRepository = 
DefualtMainRepository(retrofitApi)

}
```

and this module gets injected in my repository

```
 class DefualtMainRepository @Inject constructor(
    val retrofitApi: RetrofitApi
):MainRepository {
override suspend fun getQuotes(): Resource<RetrofitApiResponse> {

        val response = retrofitApi.getApi()
        val result = response.body()
        if (response.successful){

        }
    }
   }
```

If you are interested i have full project in my github and even wrote a medium article explaining it, Hopefully my answer is helpful to you
https://zaidzakir.medium.com/a-simple-android-app-using-mvvm-dagger-hilt-e9f45381f1bc

Comment: Can U use the Hilt in my Helper class ?Is there any possible solution ..Please help me on it

Answer (score 0):

Okay. @Zaid Zakir's answer showed me that I can inject objects via constructor parameters, if not field injection. So, the solution for me ended up looking like this.

```
@Singleton
class NetworkManager @Inject constructor(
    var defaultNetworkClient: NetworkClient
) {
    fun <R : Any> executeRequest(
            request:Request<R>,
            networkClient: NetworkClient = defaultNetworkClient
    ): Response<R> {
        // Do some operation
    }
}
```

In another class named `NetworkClientModule`, I have this,

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class NetworkClientModule {

    @Binds @Singleton
    abstract fun bindDefaultNetworkClient(impl: DefaultNetworkClient): NetworkClient

}
```

Comment: Hello @Dhunju_likes_to_Learn, I'm facing the same exact problem, but if I do it that way then I need to instantiate class to access the methods, cannot access them in the static way (like class.method()), not even using Singleton in the class annotation. In my case I need context, and if I do constructor injection for context then I need to do class(context).method total the method, and that's not what I expect.